# How do I tighten this type of plumbing connection on a pressure regulator?

Tags: plumbing, water

I have a very slow leak on the water supply line coming into my house, around where it connects with the pressure regulator valve. After wiping away the moisture around the connection, it may be a day or two before more reappears.

I'd like to try and tighten up this connection, but there seems to be multiple threaded connections going on here, and I want to make sure I don't unintentionally start loosening something. Can anyone identify what would be the proper way to tighten this connection (like where to place the wrench(s) and which direction to turn)?

[image: PRV Connection]

[image: PRV Connection Wrench Points?]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good photo! It shows someone previously used pliers or a poorly-fitting adjustable wrench on those fittings. Hopefully, you'll use a proper tool, in whatever order.

Comment: #1 and #2 are most likely a union fitting ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=plumbing+union&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Are you sure it is a leak and not condescension.  Cold water pipes and warm humid air can look like a leak.  Do you see a drop of water forming at those threads or just wet pipes?

Comment: If its not drops of water at the seam, then it may not be a leak. Please post a picture of the moisture.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a leak, the moisture only appears at this one joint, nowhere else on the pipe. The water coming in during the summer is not really that cold. I will try to add a better photo of the moisture.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be leaking at the threaded joint between 2 & 3. Hold the hex flats at 2 stationary and undo the big union nut 1. Then hold 3 stationary and unscrew the union fitting by turning the union body 2. The goal is to remove the union fitting completely so you can clean and examine, and re-seal the threads above 3, and possibly check the condition of a rubber gasket where the union mates with the regulator body at 1. Reassembly by reversing the steps. It rather looks like some sort of improper goop has been applied to the threaded pipe joint where only approved thread sealants or tape should have been used.
All threaded joints there should have typical right-hand threads.